# ALU implementation in Verilog: how to handle negative numbers?

Tags: verilog

I am designing a simple ALU with `and`, `add`, `load` operations for 16-bit inputs. This is what I have so far:

```
module ALU(overflow,out,in1,in2,select); 
input[1:0] select;
output[15:0] out;
output overflow;
reg[16:0] out;
reg overflow;
always @(in1,in2,select)

case(select)           

   0:out <= in1 & in2;    //and

   1:{overflow,out} <= in1 + in2;    //add

   2:out <= in1;         

   default: out<= 16'bx;

endcase                    
endmodule
```

I am confused how to deal with negative numbers and how to handle when my inputs are negative: what should I do?

Comment: Please correct the writing. iam -> I am
Makes it very difficult to tell what you're writing otherwise. Also place code in the proper style using the {} button.

Comment: Gustavo, just make the edit yourself next time.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of 2's complement arithmetic?  It's not the only choice, but has become the most popular, at least for general-purpose computing.

Comment: yes,i do.I was thinking in making inputs signed but in case of and operation it is logical operation doesn't deal with negative numbers

Comment: You might want to put some effort into researching what typical CPUs do.  I think you'll find that "inputs" aren't uniformly designated as signed or unsigned, but rather individual instructions interpret (or don't interpret) them that way.  For logic functions the sometimes sign bit is just another bit - and sometimes it's important to be able to manipulate it logically.

Answer (score 1):

Verilog 2001 added many extensions for signed arithmetic, including signed ports. One of the rules for arithmetic operations is if all operands are signed, then signed arithmetic will be performed.

Source: http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/online_verilog_ref_guide/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do is decide what representation you will use for negative numbers. Nearly all current systems use twos complement and I would suggest you do the same.

The great thing about twos complement is that you don't have to do anything special for addition and subtraction, they just work using exactly the same logic as unsigned arithmetic. Note that the output flag you have labelled "overflow" would normally be called "carry", it would then be common to have an "add with carry" opcode that lets you take the carry from the previous operation and add it into the next one allowing you to do arithmetic on larger numbers. Note that when adding a negative number having the carry flag set doesn't nessacerally mean overflow.

If you want to have multiplication things get a little more complex. If the input and output sizes of your multiplier are the same then an unsigned multiplier will work for twos complement but most practical multipliers have an output larger than their inputs. The explicit signed arithmetic operations in verilog 2001 can be helpful here.